# integral of $\cos{x}\cos{(\sin{x})}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I set $u=\cos{x}$, $du=-\sin{x}dx$, $dx=\frac{1}{-\sin{x}}$
$u\cos{(\sin{x})}dx$

$u [-\sin{(\sin{x})}\cos{x}(1)]+C$

$\frac{-(\sin{(\sin{x}})).(\cos{x})}{-sin{x}} + C$

tentative answer: $\sin{(\cos{x})} + C$

Another source says that the answer is $sin{(\sin{x})} + C$, and I wanted to know if and where I went wrong.

Comment: Why not u=sinx?

Comment: try u = sin(x). Then du = cos(x)dx. Your integral then becomes $\int cos(u) du= sin(u) = sin(sin(x))$.

Comment: Big hint: $\displaystyle\int \cos(\sin x)\,\underbrace{\Big(\cos x\,dx\Big)}_{\text{HINT}}$.  The point is that you want $du=\cos x\,dx$ so $u=\sin x$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $u=\sin(x) \implies \frac{du}{dx}=\cos(x)\iff du=\cos(x)dx$.

Then we have the integral $\int\cos(u)du$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$(\sin(\cos(x)))'=-\sin(x)\cos(\cos(x)),$$
$$(\sin(\sin(x)))'=\cos(x)\cos(\sin(x)).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int{\cos x\cos (\sin x)dx}=\int{\cos (\sin x)d\left( \sin x \right)}=\sin (\sin x)+C$$